# I want to delete a record in my sql with array as inputs with two where statement

Tags: php, sql-server

I want to delete a record in my sql with array as inputs with two where statement. I cant find a statement like this one...

```
"DELETE FROM perpetualinventory WHERE productID= ".implode(',',$productID)" && expiryDate=".implode(',',$expiryDate);
```

for the suggested answer

```
 "DELETE FROM perpetualinventory WHERE productID IN (".implode(',',$productID)") AND expiryDate IN (".implode(',',$expiryDate).")";
```

> syntax error, unexpected '") AND expiryDate IN ("' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Comment: Have you tried "AND" instead of "&&"?

Comment: and the error message is?

Comment: @Dagon updated my question

Comment: You are missing a dot `(".implode(',',$productID)")` should be `(".implode(',',$productID).")`  exactly what the error says `syntax error, unexpected '")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work :

```
DELETE FROM perpetualinventory WHERE productID IN ('".implode($productID,"', '")."') AND expiryDate IN ('".implode($expiryDate,"', '")."')";
```

Explanation :

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE column IN ('".
    implode($array, "'separator'") // separator = ', ' for arrays. Be careful for space after the comma.
."')
AND ...
```

Comment: But, why does it work?  Answers should explain the reason at the least, and not be just do this.

Answer (score 0):

Even it is not suggested you could do this

```
"DELETE FROM perpetualinventory WHERE productID IN (".implode(',',$productID).") AND  expiryDate IN (".implode(',',$expiryDate).")";
```

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected '") AND expiryDate IN ("' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)` returns this error

Comment: this should work now